# Do not check Geolocation on Admin page loads

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.5, magento-1.6

For finding the geo location of client based on IP and redirect to appropriate store, I use GeoIP extension and a small switch case to redirect the user. I placed the switch case in index.php file where are the pages loads through it. But I dont want to check the geolocation when the admin page loads. So if the admin is accessing the site, It dont has to check the location. It has to simply load the page. So how can I make this.

Answer (score 0):

Create new Magento module, and add a helper class to it

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Helper_Isadmin extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function isAdmin()
    {
        if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
        {
            return true;
        }

        if(Mage::getDesign()->getArea() == 'adminhtml')
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now whenever you need to check if you're in the admin, use this helper

```
if( Mage::helper('modulename/isadmin')->isAdmin() )
{
    //bypass the geoip check
}
```

Comment: if(Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin())
        {echo 'in admin';

            return true;
        }This doesnt print 'in admin' when I load admin page also.Everytime it prints else part only whether it is admin or frontend.

Comment: Eveytime Mage::getDesign()->getArea(); this prints "frontend" only whether in Admin page or frontend page. I cant really understand this. Where is the wrong goes?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem. I have installed GeoIP extension. From this we are able to get the country code based on IP. I have added a function in the observer and this will be triggered only once on the page loads with the event "controller_action_predispatch" and in the observer, I use a switch case to switch between the stores. Here is my function & switch case.

```
public function getLocationInfoByIp($observer) {

        $geoIP = Mage::getSingleton('geoip/country');
        $cnCode =  $geoIP->getCountry(); 

        switch ($cnCode) {

            case "US": {
                  Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                break;
                }
            case "IN": {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('de');
                    break;
                }
            default: {
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore('en');
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```